# How to actually use DRF + JWT Authentication with Python Requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I have a rest API for my Django 'Time Management' app. I am using the JWT(JSON Web Token) Authorization for my API. I have all the settings and views configured but I didn't clearly grasp the concept of how it actually works. I have a client for my application that will be using these auth tokens to add attendance.

Here's my project's `url.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    path('time/', include('timemanagement.urls')),
    path('api-auth', include("rest_framework.urls")),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Problem 1 - Basically, when my app first starts up, what do I want it to do?
I'm assuming I need to first make a request to `'myserver.com/api/token/'` with my username and password as headers but I don't know how I would do this with the Python Requests library.

Problem 2 - Let's say my token expired. How would my client app know that? (By sending a request with that token then I'm guessing I would get an error?) If so, how do I handle this error to get a new token? And what if that token expires too because `'api/token/refresh/'` only gives one token this time, no refresh token.

Also, every time my app loads, do I have to request a new token from 'api/token' with my Admin credentials or will there be only one token for one app that will be refreshed over and over again.
I'm not using POSTMAN, I'll be using the Python Requests Library.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't make the request `api/token` using headers, you do a POST request and pass the credentials in the body. Using Requests 2.4.2, you can do that like this:

   ```
   requests.post(
       "http://localhost:8000/api/token/",
       json={"username": "davidattenborough", "password": "boatymcboatface"}
   )
   ```
2. If your token is expired, you will get a response with status code `401`. The you call the refresh-endpoint. If your refresh token is expired, that will also give a `401`. Then you have to re-authenticate with your credentials. Using Requests, you can get the status with `.status_code`:

   ```
   response = requests.get(...)
   response.status_code
   ```

   Alternatively, you can read the expiration from the token and refresh/re-authenticate proactively. The client can read a JWT token, it can just not verify the contents. This is good enough to read the expiration time from the "exp" field. You can use the library PyJWT for that. Something like this:

   ```
   response = requests.post(
       "http://localhost:8000/api/token/",
       json={"username": "davidattenborough", "password": "boatymcboatface"}
   )
   tokens = response.json()
   access_expiration = jwt.decode(token["access"], verify=False)["exp"]
   refresh_expiration = jwt.decode(token["refresh"], verify=False)["exp"]
   ```

Comment: And there we go. A beautifully beautiful and detailed answer. Thank you sir,